# Plotting in R with Points = Levels or Rownames

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting mpg ~ wt in the R dataset mtcars and I want either the points replaced by the initial of the car model (rowname), or a legend with the rowname beside the points.

I don't know how to code for the first idea, and I get overlapping labels on the second. Is there a way of just labeling with the initial of the car model?

Stripped of colors, and other flourishes, here is the idea:

```
plot(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars); text(wt, mpg, row.names(mtcars))
```

Sorry about the ugliness... BTW I tried with ggplot2... same sort of issues...

[image]

The idea behind the replacement of the points with rowname initial came from the paper on the topic of regression by Harold Henderson:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a new variable with your short name. For the sake of this example I've taken the first letter of each rowname, but obviously there is overlap so you'll need to manually specify a `legend' column:

```
mtcars$legend <- substring(row.names(mtcars), 1, 1)
```

Then, just add `legend` as a `pch` argument:

```
plot(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars, pch = legend)
```

[image: Plot of mpg ~ wt with text labels]

As an aside, the fuel economy of American cars really hasn't improved much!